# sqlite3 - Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 4, and there are 0 supplied

Tags: python, sqlite

```
  def book():
        date = month.get(),day.get(),year.get()
        book = sqlite3.connect('bookingdatabase')
        book.execute("INSERT INTO BOOKINGDATABASE(DATE,TIME,ROOM,USERNAME) \
            VALUES (?,?,?,?)");(date,time.get(),room.get(),li1.get())
```

All the values I am getting are global variables so it would be able to find them. I have no idea why it is not working.

Comment: The error is 'Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 4, and there are 0 supplied'

Comment: see ajsp's answer which I think solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following. There is not much else to say really.

```
book.execute("INSERT INTO BOOKINGDATABASE(DATE,TIME,ROOM,USERNAME) \
 VALUES (?,?,?,?)", (date,time.get(),room.get(),li1.get()))
```

Comment: I now get this error "Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type"

Comment: @user3369770 Your question has been answered. You now have a different problem (which you should search for before posting a new question).